# how can i set a time to show something with angular?

Tags: html, angularjs

i've a search field and when i search for something and nothing is found, i show a message for user, but when has content to show, the message error appear for 3~4 seconds and after this time the message is disappear and the result of search appear...

my html:

```
<div>
  <h2>Search page</h2>
  <div class="container clearfix" ng-controller="restaurantsDataCtrl" group-by="category">

    <restaurants-gallery ng-show="restaurants.length" category="{{list.category}}" restaurants="{{list.restaurants}}" ng-repeat="list in restaurantsByCategory">

    </restaurants-gallery>

    <p ng-show="!restaurants.length">Message nothing found.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

what i need is set a time for this message appear and when this time is ended angular will know if show or not the message.

Comment: use `$timeout`. An equivalent built in service to `setTimeout`.

Comment: it mostly looks like whatever triggers the error message display should not trigger it. the error message display should be set as a callback of a successful call that does not retrieve any result.

Comment: can you post the controller code?

Comment: The typical method for showing a task is to use a spinner which will indicate to the user that something is happening. If you don't supply some indication that a process is underway they could just leave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is create a flag to indicate whether your data request has started:

```
$scope.completed = false
```

then in the callback for your data request set that flag as true:

```
...
$http.get(...).then(function(response) {
  $scope.completed = true; 
  $scope.restaurants = response.data;
}
```

if you combine that with your conditional to see if there are in fact no restaurants you can be guaranteed the message will only show up after you've tried to get data and nothing came back:

```
<p ng-show="!restaurants.length && completed">Message nothing found.</p>
```

Here's a small working example of that idea: http://plnkr.co/edit/IYtSKMHco52rHGWTT55W?p=preview